# horizontal-vertical only lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I'm new in matlab. I have a block of image as illustrated below:
[image]

Whites show pixel that their values are equal to `1` and Blacks show pixel that their values are equal to `0`,

I want to get `vertical only lines`. This means horizontal lines should be removed as illustrated below:

[image]

Also I want to get `horizontal only lines`. This means vertical lines should be removed as illustrated below:

[image]

How can I do it in `Matlab`? I prefer morphological operations for this.

Comment: i think you will need to define a few more rules, such as

1) 1 pixel can neither be horizontal, nor vertical, then shall it be removed?

2) What if a horizontal and vertical lines cross at a point, then removing the horizontal will remove a pixel from the vertical line too. How do you want to handle it?

3) Would you agree that minimum pixels required to call a set of pixels forming a line is two ?

Once you define these, it may be straight forward to detect contiguous windows of black pixels of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your image is `BW` below:

```
% detecting all connected regions:
B = bwboundaries(BW,4);
```

This results in a cell array `B` that contains all the "patches" that are made by connecting neighboring cells with value `1` that are connected from one of 4 sides, i.e. not in diagonal.

```
B = 
    [11x2 double]
    [ 2x2 double]
    [ 3x2 double]
    [ 3x2 double]
    [ 2x2 double]
    [ 3x2 double]
    [ 2x2 double]
    [ 2x2 double]
    [ 3x2 double]
    [ 3x2 double]
    [ 2x2 double]
    [11x2 double]
```

For example:

```
>> B{6}
ans =
     3     7
     3     8
     3     7
```

Each row is one cell coordinates. The first column is its' row, the second its' column, and the first and last cells are always the same.

Now we need to loop through the cells in `B`, and find which of them are lines, either horizontal or vertical, and save them to new matrices.

```
% matrices for horizontal and vertical lines:
BWh = zeros(size(BW)); % horizontal lines
BWv = zeros(size(BW)); % vertical lines
for k = 1:numel(B)
    % if the coordinates changes ONLY vertically:
    % a vertical line is where all the coulmn indecies are the same
    % and there are different row indices
    if all(B{k}(1,2)==B{k}(:,2)) && B{k}(1,1)~=B{k}(2,1) 
        BWv(sub2ind(size(BW),B{k}(:,1),B{k}(:,2))) = 1;
    end
    % if the coordinates changes ONLY horizontaly:
    % a vertical line is where all the row indecies are the same
    % and there are different column indices
    if all(B{k}(1,1)==B{k}(:,1)) && B{k}(1,2)~=B{k}(2,2)
        BWh(sub2ind(size(BW),B{k}(:,1),B{k}(:,2))) = 1;
    end
end
subplot 131
imagesc(BWh)
title('Horizontal lines')
subplot 132
imagesc(BWv)
title('Vertical lines')
```

The "Diagonal edges" are what left after we exclude the lines, so we can just look for what we didn't find so far:

```
subplot 133
imagesc(BW & ~BWv & ~BWh)
title('Diagonal edges')
colormap 'gray'
```

[image: BWvh]

This method will ignore anything that is not a one-cell thick line, so for instance, the square in the middle in the image below will be shown only in the **Diagonal edges** pattern:

[image: box demo]

Comment: excuse me, is there any way to recognize diagonal-only edges? I prefer to do it without using image subtraction.

Comment: Dear `EBH`, If it is possible for you, please provide more comments about the 'How your algorithm is performing'

Comment: @Babak.Abad I will add more commentary in few hours. What are _diagonal-only edges_?

Comment: Diagonal edges mean pixel that are not included in (horizontal and vertical lines). For example, In your last image, Pixels at (8,2), (4,6) are diagonal. also it can not be single as seen in point (6,12). I apologize for my mistakes about not defining diagonal edges and my bad English writing. Also thank you again for the time that you consume for my questions.

Comment: @Babak.Abad see my edit for more explanations and the "Diagonal edges" extracting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete and comprehensive answer and recently update. All of your approaches outperform my approaches (connected components analysis) in terms of speed and complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, because there's so many ways to do that.
In essence you need to take out consecutive pixels of a spesific dimension.
One way I see to solve this is to convolve with a `[1 1]` or `[1 1]'` vector and then take out all the elements where you get the values 2.

```
bw(conv2(bw,[1 1],'same')==2)=0;
```

this will still leave single pixels that you can take out easily using

```
bw = bwareaopen(bw,2) ;
```

this is just the main idea, you probably need to be more careful around the edges, or pad with zeros to avoid edge artifacts that conv2 can make)...

Another idea, use the [Hough transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/hough-transform.html) to detect lines and keep only those with theta=0 or 90 deg...

Comment: Thank you, for answers. A new way... But second answer is correct and complete. +1 for your answer