# Removing single pixels Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I have a binary image. I have several single pixels in images. Single pixels are white (1) and all of their neighborhoods are black (0). for example image below shows a single pixel (at center) and two pixels (at left-bottom):

0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 **1** 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
**1 1** 0 0 0

How can I remove single pixels with morphological operations in Matlab?

Comment: What happens at the boundaries? i.e. if the `1` is placed on one of the edges of the image, so it's not surrounded by `0` from all sides?

Comment: Since you explicitly asked for morphological operations: `bwmorph` has a  'clean' option which is described as "Removes isolated pixels (individual 1s that are surrounded by 0s)" with an example close to yours. Have a look: https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html

Comment: please write your solution in answer section. The point is yours @Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon request by the OP, I'm converting my short comment into a reply:

Since you explicitly asked for morphological operations: bwmorph has a 'clean' option which is described as "Removes isolated pixels (individual 1s that are surrounded by 0s)" with an example close to yours. Have a look at the [bwmorph](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

I give you another option without loop, using a 2D convolution with `conv2`:

```
M = [0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0]

C = [0 1 0
     1 1 1
     0 1 0]; % The matrice that is going to check if a `1` is alone or not.

%if you also want to consider the neibhbors on the diagonal choose:
%C = ones(3);

R = M.*conv2(M,C,'same')>1 %Check for the neighbors.
```

**RESULT**

```
R =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: C = ones(3) does not work . It adds two new pixels as **1**  in the 4th row (row index counting from 1)

Comment: M = [0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0] does not work when not considering diagonals

Comment: R = M .* conv2(M,C,'same') > 1

Comment: @user009122 you're right, I've update this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185373/horizontal-vertical-only-lines), you can use `bwboundaries`:

if `P` is the binary image, than:

```
B = bwboundaries(P,8);
for k = 1:numel(B)
    if size(B{k})<=2
        P(B{k}(1,1),B{k}(1,2)) = 0;
    end
end
```

So for the example above `P` becomes:

```
P =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but it seems that your answer is not based on morphological operations. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Babak.Abad I'm not sure what are _morphological operations_, but it probably doesn't.